# VB6 val(parseString()) gives type mismatch but not when debug

Tags: vb6, double, type-mismatch

I have code that assigns a value to a double array. It seems to through an error "Type Mismatch".

```
datamax(i) = val(parseString(curpos, dummy, delimit))
```

The crazy thing is that if I debug.print out what is in the val() function first, the error does not happen.

```
Debug.Print parseString(curpos, dummy, delimit)
datamax(i) = val(parseString(curpos, dummy, delimit))
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Show the code for parseString, and the input values (the values of `curpos`, `dummy`, `delimit`)

Comment: [Show me the code, Show me the code!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaiSHcHM0PA)

Comment: Val() is generally a poor choice, because it isn't localized and always treats "." as the decimal point.  CDbl() would be the preferred choice in most cases.  Just a side comment though, and it doesn't explain your Type Mismatch.  Seems obvious that your parseString() is where the trouble lies.

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell what is wrong because you did not show enough code, but if I were to hazard a guess on why it works with the DebugPrint in front I'd say the parameters sent to parseString are ByRef and are being updated.  On the second call the result must be slightly different.  Try doing two Debug.Prints in a row:

```
Debug.Print "--->" & parseString(curpos, dummy, delimit) & "<---"
Debug.Print "--->" & parseString(curpos, dummy, delimit) & "<---"
```

And see if the value is the same each time.